# Finding the minimal polynomial of $uv$, when those of $u$ and $v$ are given and of degree three

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials, resultant

Let $k \subseteq L$ be a finite separable field extension (not necessarily Galois) of degree $3$, and assume that $L=k(u)=k(v)$, for some $u,v \in L$. Clearly, $k \subseteq k(uv) \subseteq k(u)=k(v)$, and since 
$[L:k(uv)][k(uv):k]=[L:k]=3$, we get that $k(uv)=k$ or $k(uv)=L$.
Further assume that $k(uv)=L$.

Denote the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $k$ by $A(t)=t^3+at+b$,
and the minimal polynomial of $v$ over $k$ by $B(t)=t^3+ct+d$, where $a,b,c,d \in k$.

> What is the minimal polynomial of $uv$ over $k$, in terms of $a,b,c,d \in k$?

Notice that this question is a special case of [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609838/minimal-polynomial-of-ab-when-those-of-a-and-b-are-known).

**Remark:**

Generlly, the minimal polynomial of $u$ over $k$ is of the form: 
$t^3+et^2+at+b$, $e,a,b \in k$.

We can assume that $e=0$ from the following reason:
$t^3+3\frac{e}{3}t^2+3\frac{e^2}{9}t+\frac{e^3}{27}+(b-\frac{e^3}{27}) -3\frac{e^2}{9}t+at
= (t-\frac{e}{3})^3+(a-\frac{e^2}{3})(t-\frac{e}{3}+\frac{e}{3})+(b-\frac{e^3}{27})=(t-\frac{e}{3})^3+(a-\frac{e^2}{3})(t-\frac{e}{3})+[(a-\frac{e^2}{3})\frac{e}{3}+(b-\frac{e^3}{27})]$

Denote $\tilde{a}:= (a-\frac{e^2}{3})$ and $\tilde{b}:=(a-\frac{e^2}{3})\frac{e}{3}+(b-\frac{e^3}{27})$, and $\tilde{u}:=u-\frac{e}{3}$.

Then $\tilde{u}$ is a root of $\tilde{A}:=t^3+\tilde{a}t+\tilde{b}$; 
indeed, $\tilde{A}(\tilde{u})=(\tilde{u})^3+\tilde{a}(\tilde{u})+\tilde{b}=0$.
It is clear that $k(u)=k(u-\frac{e}{3})=k(\tilde{u})$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what makes you think that the answer would be different ??

Comment: I do not think that the answer would be different. I just wish to see an accurate computation of the special case of degree three. Can you please help me with that?