# Is linear disjunction a polynomial condition?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Linked to my recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438163/minimal-polynomial-of-product-sum-etc-of-two-algebraic-numbers/2613864#2613864), I would like to know if linear disjunction is a polynomial condition.

Technically, for each $p,q\in \mathbb{N}_+$, is there a polynomial of two variables $D_{p,q}(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that, for any algebraic field extension $F\subset \Omega$, and $\alpha,\beta\in \Omega$ with $[F(\alpha),F]=p,\ [F(\beta),F]=q$, one has 
$$
D_{p,q}(\alpha,\beta)\not=0\Longleftrightarrow [F(\alpha,\beta),F]=pq
$$
or - at least - implies ? (with $D\not\equiv 0$)